# How do I access the components of a private RSA key in Python's cryptography module?

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, pyopenssl, python-cryptography

I'm not finding an API, but because it seems to delegate to OpenSSL, perhaps I'm not understanding how this works.

What I'm looking for is the equivalent of the first answer to this [1] but from within Python, using an RSA keypair that has just been generated and, for security reasons, has never been written to disk.

[1] [How do I extract the private key components $N$ and $D$ from a private RSA key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066752/how-do-i-extract-the-private-key-components-n-and-d-from-a-private-rsa-key)

Comment: maybe this? https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call [private_numbers](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPrivateKeyWithSerialization.private_numbers) on your `RSAPrivateKey` object. This will return an [RSAPrivateNumbers](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPrivateNumbers) object that has integer forms of the key components.

Comment: What about the other way around? If I have those private numbers, how can I reconstitute the PrivateKey object? (This API sure is trying hard to keep people from touching hazardous material ...)

Comment: You can build an RSAPrivateNumbers object and then call `private_key` on it to convert it to a key object that can perform cryptographic operations.

Comment: @JohannesErnst that's because the writers are security conscious, and most implementation vulnerabilitys are because of id10t user errors.